# In R, is it possible set the title of a Cairo window?

Tags: r, cairo

I'm outputting several plots via the Cairo package in R. But having five windows titled "Cairo Graphics" makes it hard to find the right one in the taskbar.

Is there anyway to change the text in the title bar?

**These did NOT work:**

- `CairoWin(title="Hello")`
- `windows.options(title="Hello"); CairoWin()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the window title is hard-coded in the Cairo source code (in `w32-backend.c`):

```
window gawin = newwindow("Cairo Graphics", rect(20,20,width,height),
                         Document|StandardWindow);
```

So the answer is no, unless you want to patch and recompile it the package.